# Show menu link as expanded when on node pages for a content type?

Tags: 7, routes

I need to show a menu link as expanded when you are on the node page of a certain content type.

These nodes don't actually have menu link but are navigated to, through a menu link and taxonomy terms.

Comment: You could use the Context Module for this (http://drupal.org/project/context).

Comment: Its not immediately clear to me how but its such a powerful module I can believe it. Seems very overkill for a small bit of functionality that I require.

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote? Its not very helpfull with no explanation, I dont know what ive done wrong so I cant avoide doing it again.

Comment: @jdln: I did not cast the down vote, and I agree it would be helpful to clarify when downvoting. Maybe because a google search would have easily brought up the answer? EDIT: Which you found yourself, I realize :)

Comment: It's frustrating (I think) when downvoters do NOT explain why they do so. It prevents you from "learning from mistakes", right? But don't worry too much about downvotes. And don't think too much like "what did I do wrong" ... instead rather like "hm, somebody who has another OPINION", or trying to express "that would not be a good idea". That doesn't make the question a bad one. Moreover be aware that downvoting QUESTIONS does not cost "any" reputation to the downvoter (like the -1 when downvoting an answer ...), so downvoting questions is cheap ... AND: some day a +1 may come in, like today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu Trail By Path modules does this is the node's paths are children of the parent.
http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path